# Wordpress Category Page Not reading CSS File

Tags: css, wordpress

So I'm building out an ecommerce part of a wordpress site. http://www.bluestarnj.com. Now when I go to list out a product category like here: http://www.bluestarnj.com/?it_exchange_category=odcp

I get an unformatted list for each of my products. I'd like to format these CSS classes, such as class=entry_content and class=it-exchange-product, but firebug is showing me that these classes are not linked to any known css files on my server. I've properly called the get header and footer functions in the category.php file so I'm totally perplexed as to why it can't find the CSS files associated with those CSS classes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Baroti

Comment: you check the css typo error in your class name so didn,t shown

Comment: Are you talking about class=it_exchange_product ? because in the actual css file provided by the exchange plugin it is listed with dashes not underscores. A CSS validator pulls the code as       #it-exchange-product .it-exchange-product-no-images {
    float : none; }
Either way the css is not being pulled into the category page for any of the ids or classes whether I place them in the main wordpress CSS or the exchange overide CSS files and that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/wp-content/themes/BLUESTAR/style.css, line 475:

```
.it-exchange-product li{
```

Should be:

```
li.it-exchange-product
```

What you have there is class first, element second, which CSS reads as: element with class .it-exchange-product is the parent of element li. CSS should see it as element with a class of it-exchange-product.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Been there, done that, that's how I learned :D in CSS it's always parent first, child second and element first, class of that same element second. However, if you have for example <div class="class"><li></li></div>, then it's .class li.

Answer (score 0):

Um are you including the header.php file in your category file ? There might be a parent css file that you haven't included

Comment: Yep, i'm calling the header just like in my index.php or any of my page-____.php files. here is a push of the code. http://puu.sh/euBKP/d10b4db74b.png

Comment: What  also don't understand is that it pulls the css for the div id=archive_content, but not for div id=entry-content so it is clearly pulling the css from my header.php if it can read the archive_content css #id